# How can I make the keyoutput dependent on what window the mouse is over?

Tags: autohotkey

So if the mouse is over msedge a key should have a different meaning. I have seen the [MouseGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) , OutputVarX, OutputVarY, OutputVarWin, function but I dont know how to apply it correctly.

Comment: See [#If - Syntax & Usage Example 1](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#ExVolume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution using the [WinGet command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm).

You may also want to consult the quick reference on the [WinTitle parameter](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm). Anytime a command accepts a `WinTitle` parameter, you can pass a window:

- Unique ID
- Title
- Group
- Owning processes PID

...among a few others.

The `OutputVarWin` data from `MouseGetPos` will return a unique window ID. To use the window ID in the `WinTitle` parameter, prefix it with `ahk_id` (example below).

Now, my example uses a hotkey (Ctrl + Shift + D) to fire. You may have a condition enclosed in a loop or something, so I think anything below the hotkey declaration (`^+D::`) will be most relevant to you.

```
^+D::       ;User presses Ctrl + Shift + D to fire this routine
MouseGetPos,,,hWindowID
WinGet,szProcess,ProcessName,ahk_id %hWindowID%     ;Prefixed with ahk_id so AHK knows it's a unique window ID
if(szProcess="msedge.exe")
    MsgBox Mouse is over Edge!
else
    MsgBox Mouse isn't over Edge!
return
```

Comment: But for some funny reason, the MsgBox "Mouse isnt over edge" is shown when I press ^+D and the MsBox "Mouse is over Edge!" isnt shown .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#IfWinActive`. This ensures that the hotkeys below the statement are only activated when a certain window is active.

Note 1: this directive is applied to everything below, unless you tell the script otherwise.

Note 2: this doesn't depend on which window the mouse is over, but which window is currently activated.

See: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

An example from one of my scripts:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass    ;Shortcuts for windows explorer 

    ;Ctrl + numpad + is resize all columns to fit. Make sure this works for ctrl+=. 
    ^=::Send,{LCtrl down}{NumpadAdd}{LCtrl up}

#IfWinActive ;Make sure everything below is not keyed to Windows Explorer
```